# Why can't I override tabSelectedTextColor using a "theme" but "style" works fine?

Tags: android

My understanding is that using "android:theme" is the same as "style" except it applies to children views as well. I don't understand why the following happens:

Using "android:theme":

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:theme="@style/TabsLight"/>
```

I get the following tab style:

[image]

Using "style" instead:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    style="@style/TabsLight" />
```

I get the font colour as white on the tabs correctly as I want:

[image]

Even though in both cases, I'm mapping to the same style:

```
<style name="TabsLight" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/TabsTextLight</item>
    <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">#ffffff</item>
 </style>

<style name="TabsTextLight" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:textColor">#cccccc</item>
</style>
```

Comment: did you find a solution?